# How to update the List of Webelements on the page?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, functional-testing

As in the title - how to correctly refresh the "productList" to finally find the specific product in the catalogue?

this method clicks all the time in the button "Show Next Products" even if the product itself is visible on the page. It means that the "productList" hasn't been refreshed.

```
   public void findProductAndAddToCart()  {

        //searching for products by className
        List<WebElement> productList = SeleniumDriver.getDriver().findElements(By.className("bcom--txtBold"));

    for (int i = 0; i < productList.size(); i++) {
        //getting the numbers of the products
        String element = productList.get(i).getText();

        if (element.equals("7000029644")) {
            productList.get(i).isDisplayed();
            System.out.println("Product is displayed");
            SeleniumDriver.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("XPATH - Add to Cart Button')]")).click();
            break;

        } else {

            //the product hasn't been found, so need to click "Show Next Products"
            SeleniumDriver.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Show Next')]")).click();
            List<WebElement> newProductList = SeleniumDriver.getDriver().findElements(By.className("bcom--txtBold"));
            productList.addAll(newProductList);


        }
```

[image: Product]
[image: Show Next Products Button]
[image: Add to Cart Button]

[image: Output from the console]

Comment: If I am reading this right do you mean to say that you don't see "Product is displayed" in the console ? and rather the execution goes to else statement ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is searching all the time..

Comment: Can you share the URL so we can give it a try as well

Comment: I wish I could. This is testing environament of in-house company website where credentials are needed, which I cannot reveal ;//

Comment: I've added. 1) product number 2) Show Next Button 3) Add to Cart Button

Comment: Toggle a breakpoint at the `if` case and debug step by step

Comment: The driver gets Text of just ONE/FIRST element on the page and then if the name doesn't equil the product name - it click Show Next Products. And the over and over again it finds one element and clicks Show Next Button.

Comment: Okay, and what do you get when you sysout `productList.size()` - If the output is one then that's where the issue is, If the output is >1 then do a sysout on `element ` within your `for` loop and see if the values are iterated

Comment: productList.size() shows a lot of webelements on the site. The thing is that.. it doesn't iterate through the visible webelements(products), but it clicks "Next Products". I also did the sysout on the element so the behaviour is like that: 1) Find one product number 2) Clicks Show Next Button 3) Find second product number 4) Clicks Show Next Button. So.... if the correct product number is on the 50th position, then it clicks 50 times of "Show Next Product". And currently, there are 8 visible products on the page until I should click "Show Next Products"

Comment: Beti, its a bit confusing ! The return type for productList.size() is int so does it return a number >1 ? and also what do you get when you sysout on `element` ?

Comment: productList.size() shows exactly 39. There are 8 products visible on the page. When the product is on the first page, there is no issue. The problem is when the driver needs to search for it and clicks "Show Next..."

Comment: I don't mind, but for next 2h I have online meetings, so if possible I would be available in 2h. Is that ok?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
public void findProductAndAddToCart() {

    boolean flag = true;

    while (flag) {
      flag = isNextEnabled();

      //searching for products by className
      List<WebElement> productList = SeleniumDriver.getDriver()
          .findElements(By.className("bcom--txtBold"));

      for (WebElement e : productList) {

        //getting the numbers of the products
        String element = e.getText();

        if (element.equals("7000029644")) {
          e.isDisplayed();
          System.out.println("Product is displayed");
          SeleniumDriver.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("XPATH1')]")).click();
          flag = false;
          break;

        } else {
          //don't click next here
          }
      }
          SeleniumDriver.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Show 
   Next')]")).click();
    }
  }

  private boolean isNextEnabled() {
    return SeleniumDriver.getDriver()
        .findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Show Next')]")).isEnabled;
  }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the idea, however it keeps clicking in the "Show Next Button', even if the product is visible in the catalog. ;/

Comment: if you print the productList to console, are you seeing the product that you are looking for?

Comment: The product is not visible on the displayed page, because I need to click "Show Next...". When it was on the first page, there was no problem. The issue is that every iteration of element - the driver clicks the button. So if I want to find the product which is on the 14th position - the driver clicks 14 times the button, which is not necessary because I need to click only once, because the product is on the 2nd page displayed.

Comment: can you try the code i posted? It will first iterate through all the elements in first page and if doesn't find only then will click the next button. So after it clicks next button, during the list iteration your product should be found. So basically the code I posted will keep repeating iterating over a list & click next until it finds a product or there are no more next

Comment: I did a screenshot of outputs from the console and updated above.

Comment: I used your code. What I need is the ELEMENT name that is matching the product number. And... I get only ONE element and then product list which is only found by ClassName... then driver is clicking in the "Show More Products" ..and then the second element in this List is gettingText and then I get the second element. then... again clicking on the button.